# Single sign on with Microsoft Azure in Flutter with oAuth2

Tags: flutter, azure, oauth-2.0, oauth

I have been trying to create a Flutter app that uses SSO with my freshly made Microsoft Azure account. I have decided on [oauth2](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2) dependency, but I'm not sure what to put in redirect() and listen() methods.

Also, does my Azure App need to be web or mobile based? Any special tweaks?
Do I need a local web server running since it's accessing localhost?